# How to create a Premium_LRS SSD disk resource (my problem is probably not python specific)

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to create a `Premium SSD` disk to attach to a VM in azure but can't seem to figure out how to specify that correctly - I keep ending up with a `Standard HDD`.

```
azure_client.compute_client.disks.create_or_update("my_resource_group", 'deleteme-' + str(disk_num), {
    "location": "westus",
    "disk_size_gb": 256,
    'creation_data': {
        'create_option': 'empty',
        'sku': {
            'name': 'Premium_LRS' # <=== What I want
        }
    },
    'tags': {
        "fake": "tags"
    }
}).result().as_dict()
{
    'id': '/subscriptions/5efe2633-26ac-4638-9f1f-6e24e494d9b4/resourceGroups/my_resource_group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/deleteme-26',
    'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded',
    'name': 'deleteme-26',
    'type': 'Microsoft.Compute/disks',
    'time_created': '2019-02-05T00:37:41.907815Z',
    'tags': {
        'fake': 'tags'
    },
    'creation_data': {
        'create_option': 'Empty'
    },
    'sku': {
        'tier': 'Standard',
        'name': 'Standard_LRS' # <== What I actually get
    },
    'location': 'westus',
    'disk_size_gb': 256
}
```

I'm open to connecting the disk directly to the host at creation, but can't figure out the API for tagging the disk that way.

I've also tried also specifying `'tier': 'Premium'` in the sku description - but no change.  Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/disks/createorupdate#diskstorageaccounttypes) I've found:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit embarrassing, but maybe someone else will do this in the future... I put the SKU in the wrong sub-dictionary.   Azure doesn't yell at you if you put random stuff it doesn't understand in the `creation_data` section.

```
azure_client.compute_client.disks.create_or_update("my_resource_group", 'deleteme-' + str(disk_num), {
    "location": "westus",
    "disk_size_gb": 256,
    'creation_data': {
        'create_option': 'empty'
    },
    'sku': {
        'name': 'Premium_LRS' # <=== Moved out of creation_data dict
    }
    'tags': {
        "fake": "tags"
    }
}).result().as_dict()
```